# Как создать объект стека

Tags: c++, c++builder

До использования билдера создавал стек так:

```
list< string > stack;
```

или так (нашел в интернете)

```
stack <string> st;
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку

```
[bcc32 Error] Unit16.cpp(19): E2451 Undefined symbol 'list'
Full parser context
Unit16.cpp(19): parsing: void _fastcall TForm16::Button1Click(TObject *)
```

И так с каждым элементом: list, string, stack и т.д.
В чем может быть ошибка, и возможен ли вообще такой способ создания стека?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для использования `std::stack` нужно использовать заголовок `#include <stack>`, для `std::list` - `#include <list>` и т.д.

Comment: Я знаю, но это не помогает.

Comment: Решилось так:
std::list <String> stack;
std::stack <String> st;

Comment: `String` это что-то из билдера. В C++ это `std::string` в заголовке `<string>`